# How to enable WebGL in the electron browser?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I am using `electron main.js` to display a webpage.

By default, `electron` has WebGL enabled. But I still get **no WebGL support detected** error.

What am I missing? Is there some magic `apt-get install` to fix it? Or some special specifications in `electron`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need enable the experimental OpenGL driver.

`sudo raspi-config`

under "Advanced Options". As indicated  , this driver is
experimental. Backup your SD card first.